# What's the advantage of using drupal's module_load_include vs. just including a file?

Tags: drupal

What's the advantage of using drupal's module_load_include vs. just including a file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

module_load_include will find the path to the module listed and then the file inside that module's folder, which in some multi-site (or now, with installation profiles) can be different.  It's just a step to reduce the code needed to be generalized enough for the entire community.

Comment: it may be less clear if you're including a file in your own module - it's probably just in a subfolder.  If you're including from another module however, you never know if it's in sites/all/modules, sites/default/modules, etc....  Module_load_include will also return false if the file doesn't exist, rather than throwing a PHP error

Comment: Though @GApple s usecase is a pretty common one, it still is a bad one. Modules should never include eachothers files. Ever. It breaks all concept of modularisation, leaving you in a depedency hell waiting to happen.